# Android dialog from thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In a background thread started with AsyncTask I request root access. If it's denied (su not found), I want to tell the user. I know you can't directly post to the UI thread from a background thread, but doing so through a reference to the main activity seemed to work well when I tested it. Now that it's published to the market, though, these errors are reported:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not     called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:100)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:96)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:891)
at com.sajarvis.albert.AlbertActivity.onCreateDialog(AlbertActivity.java:357)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2747)
at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:948)
at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2825)
at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2789)
at com.sajarvis.albert.AlbertActivity$HiyaTask.doInBackground(AlbertActivity.java:507)
at com.sajarvis.albert.AlbertActivity$HiyaTask.doInBackground(AlbertActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 4 more
```

Here's the code in the dialog creator (lines 349-360)

```
case 1: //su denied
    Log.w(TAG,"Su denied failure");
    builder
        .setTitle(R.string.su_denied_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.su_denied_message)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
    }).create();
break;
```

And lines 501-511 in the background thread, where I call the dialog on fail.

```
//Get ROOT access.
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    //TODO crashes here
    activity.showDialog(1);
    FlurryAgent.onError("4","su denied","Fail");

    return success; //False, fail.
}
```

Is activity.showDialog(1); what's causing the crash? If so, why does it not crash consistently. If it isn't, any idea what is? Thanks much.

Comment: What thread are you creating your AsyncTask on? and Where in your AsyncTask is the AlertDialog creation started?

Comment: I create the task from the main activity, the UI thread. The only line in the AsyncTask for the dialog is activity.showDialog(1). That calls onCreateDialog() in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code still attempts to show dialog from background thread.

In you particular case, what you want to do is to return a result from  `doInBackground()` and if result indicates that `su` can't be found, show dialog in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will make some changes. Is there a reason for the inconsistency? It works on an unrooted HTC Incredible, the emulator, and an unrooted tablet.